# Null pointer errors with Static methods

Tags: c#

I have getting a number of error reports from an application of mine that don't seem to make any sense. I have a static class that has a number of public static methods that are called from other parts of my code. Most of these methods create an element on an XML document.

The first line in most of these methods is a call to a private static method in this same class which creates the element on the XML doc and returns it, like so:

```
private static XmlElement BuildCmd(string name)
{
  XmlElement e = OtherClass.NewElement("CMD");
  e.SetAttribute("type", name);
  return e;
}

public static uint SendFlightReport(FlightData info, AircraftInfo aInfo)
{
  XmlElement cmd = BuildCmd("pirep");
  ....
  some other stuff
  ....
}
```

The stack dumps generated by the exception all report the line calling BuildCmd as the offending line, which makes no sense - how can you have a null pointer (or, in C# - Object reference not set to an instance of an object) when calling a static method?

EDIT: For those who asked, here is the code to OtherClass.NewElement:

```
public class OtherClass {

   private readonly XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

   public XmlElement NewElement(string name) {
      lock (doc)
        return doc.CreateElement(name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible culprits: `OtherStaticClass` (maybe a static constructor) or `e` (the return value of `OtherStaticClass.NewElement`). Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Please show us "some other stuff".  I have (sadly, with great frequency) had to wrestle with the fact that the line numbers in stack traces in production environments are often completely wrong.  It is (painfully) obvious that `BuildCmd("pirep")` cannot conceivably throw an NRE.  So it isn't.   However, the method names in the stack traces are never wrong. So if it is indeed blaming `SendFlightReport`, then the NRE is *defintely* happening there.  Please post the whole method.

Comment: I think it would be valuable to show the implementation of "OtherStaticClass.NewElement..."

Comment: I'm going to agree with @M.Babcock. Everything else looks fine, can you post the code for `OtherStaticClass.NewElement`?

Comment: Sorry - actually BuildCmd doesn't call a static class; my apologies. It calls a static instance of a class that is defined as readonly and is guaranteed not to be null. It's been called dozens of times in the program flow before, and only errors out this one time.

Comment: Can I post the code in a comment?

Comment: @LukeKolin Just edit your post with new/updated code

Comment: Since `BuildCmd` doesn't call `OtherClass.NewElement` statically, are you sure `OtherClass` has been instantiated?

Comment: Quite certain. It's declared as a static readonly variable initialized when the static class is created. I try to do as many readonly variables as possible to guarantee state.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are running a release build.  The line numbers are often slightly off in that case, because of compiler optimizations.  Try running a debug build; you'll probably find that the exception is actually being thrown on the first or second line of `.... some other stuff ....`

See, for example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/114854/385844

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vsdebug/thread/afb7ae70-3e0c-4ea9-86ab-633fe1f9cf6a (VB.NET, but still...)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/6af62159-fe6b-4554-8e46-d2b6c06fa253

Comment: I didn't downvote but it seems you're assuming the code in the question came directly from the OP's actual code... that's a pretty broad assumption based on what we've seen in questions here on SO.

Comment: Is that the case? I've never seen this before with other stack traces.

Comment: @LukeKolin I see it all the time at work (like Kirk Woll, apparently), but I'm not at work now.  I just tried to reproduce this with a simple program, with no luck.  I'll see if I can come up with something tomorrow when I get to the office.